# How to create a variable taking value X+1 if an event doesn't occur in X periods?

Tags: stata, dummy-variable, recode

How can I create a new variable that takes value X+1 if an event doesn't occur in X periods of time?

Specifically, I have data of many people in 12 years. For a question, they could answer yes (1) or no(0). I care the first time someone says Yes during 12 years and  created a variable that takes value of the number of years with Yes replies.

But if someone replies No for 12 years, I set value of that variable equal 13. But I'm stuck at how to do that.

```
by hhidpn (wave), sort: gen byte EarlyHeart = sum(rhearte) == 1
gen EarlyHeart1=year if EarlyHeart==1
(what's next?)
```

Comment: but i dont need all missing values equal 13, I only need 13 wherever i see answer NO for all 12 years (i.e., sum(rhearte) is always 0)

Comment: I'm sorry, I deleted my comment, it was wrong.

Comment: `by hhidpn: egen first1 = min(EarlyHeart1)` then `by hhidpn: rep first1=13 if first1==.`

Comment: no it's because of my poor explanation from the beginning... It still doesn't work William :(

Comment: thanks a lot William, I have found out a way. I will delete this topic now :)

Answer (score 0):

If the last cumulative sum for an individual is 0, then they all are.

```
by hhidpn (wave), sort: gen byte EarlyHeart = sum(rhearte) == 1
by hhidpn : replace EarlyHeart = 13 if EarlyHeart[_N] == 0
```